# Styling/labeling specific features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, vector, style

I need to styling/labeling some specific features in a vector layer. I thought I could use the rule-based option in the style/label window with a "field=value" expression if i have only one specific feature.

Which expression I should use if I have many specific features?

Comment: `"field" IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')` etc.

Comment: if I understood correctly it should be, i.e .: "codice IN (13, 15, 18)" for the specific features, "codice=ELSE" for all the other features?

Comment: Careful with your quotes. Use double for field names; single for values. You can create two rules, the first can have the expression: `"codice" IN ('13', '15', '18')`. The second rule can have `"codice" = 'ELSE'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where could I find some informations about creating expressions and their syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following expression to style/label specific attribute values:

```
"fieldName" IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

---

For more information, you can check the [QGIS documentation for expressions.](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#vector-expressions)